# JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get a few informations from the pokeapi but I keep getting the JSONDecodeError when searching for the form of certain pokemons. When I search for charmander it works, but when I search for pidgey doesn't.
Here's the code:

```
pokename = input('Digite o nome do Pokémon que você deseja consultar: ')

formas = requests.get(f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/{pokename}/')
forms_data = formas.json()
```

And here's the error:

```
Digite o nome do Pokémon que você deseja consultar: pidgey
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/perei/Evylla/DEV/python/pokemons.py", line 14, in <module>
status_data = status.json()
File "C:\Users\perei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", 
line 898, in json
return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\perei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in 
loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\perei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in 
decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\perei\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in 
raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: You obviously aren’t getting a JSON response - have you tried printing the response, or saving to file (before trying futilely to decode as JSON) so you can examine the response?

Comment: I didn't just try to decode as JSON because I thought it was pretty, I have other requests that worked exactly like this. That was the only one that was giving me an error, and I wanted to understand why, since opening the link  and replacing 'pokename' for the name of the pokemon I wanted was working. But I figured out already, thank you.

Comment: The response won’t decode as JSON: all you have to do is examine the response to find out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably with your input `pokename`. The api might be returning 404 for malformed `pokename`

try the below code.

```
import requests

#replace xx by bulbasaur and the code will print JSON.
k = requests.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/xx') 
if k.status_code == 200:
    print(k.json())
else:
    print("error",k.status_code)
```